# Use TLS and disable SSL in Android

Tags: android, ssl, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection, tls1.2

I want to create a secure connection between an android client and a delphi server. It is recommended to use TLS1.1 or TLS1.2 and an **self signed** certificate.

For now the minimum sdk version is 19.

I figured out how to connect with a self signed certificate. But it seems that the android client always tries to connect with SSLv3. I tried to disable SSLv3 and only use TLS, but i did not find a suitable solution which minds a self signed certificate.

P.s.: Wihtout any secure layer or with SSLv3 the connection is working if I tell the server to use none or the SSLv3

```
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x71698c50: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x388da166:0x00000000)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at de.gold_software.wartungsmanager.server.TestController$TestAsyncTask.doInBackground(TestController.java:119)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at de.gold_software.wartungsmanager.server.TestController$TestAsyncTask.doInBackground(TestController.java:66)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-25 13:19:10.418 10247-10291/de.gold_software.wartungsmanager W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The Code of my Asynctask

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
caInput = new BufferedInputStream(getMyContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.proxyserver));
Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);

String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

URL url = new URL("https://192.168.1.177:443");
conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
conn.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
```

instead of
`SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");` ?

Another thing could be:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLS"); //somewhere in Java code, in main f.e.
```

or maybe even

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1"); //worked by me
```

But be carefully, this settings will be saved for a long time.

Also in your Java JRE folder you can find file jre/lib/security/java.security, where you can find such a line and change it or just add this line (only if not exists):

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3
```

Or combine the two last solutions.